# Symfony 2 HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: symfony

I'v [HWIO Exemple](http://nyrodev.info/fr/posts/286/Connexions-OAuth-Multiple-avec-Symfony-2-3) Tuto, and i got this error :

**Unable to find the controller for path "/oauth/login/check-facebook". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?**

Any One have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this bundle but maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md#user-content-c-import-the-routing

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-configuring_the_security_layer.md

Comment: thanks, my route is already configurated.. when i delete them, i get other error, so symfony detect there routes..

Comment: This seems a misconfiguration issue, are you sure `/oauth/login/check-facebook` is a managed route. Try checking with `php app/console router:debug`

Comment: I Found it in router:debug .. this may complicate things .. (facebook_login          ANY     ANY    ANY  /oauth/login/check-facebook)

Answer (score 0):

forget the "check-" this is the url used by hwioauthbundle to receive the access_token

try /oauth/login/facebook or /login/facebook

Comment: Thanks you, i've tried other url like "facebook-test" and i have the same error :(

Comment: `$this->generateUrl('hwi_oauth_service_redirect', array('service'=>'facebook')`  ?

Comment: this line return as well "/oauth/connect/facebook" and the connectController redirect to "oauth/check-facebook", but in the file cache "DevUrlGenerator", i found "facebook_login" without "_coontroller", don't know why :(